# Big Data Processing In Java

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-beam

I am working on one project where I am receiving somewhere around 10 files each containing size of 200GB. My Project requirement is to extract data from each file and do the joining with other files and extract the data.

E.G like I have file 1.txt where I have Account Id and I have file 2.txt, where I have Account Id and Account Name. On the Basis of the Account Id from the first file I need to extract the data from the second file.

This way I need to perform manipulation on each of the 10 files and create final output files.

I am currently doing this in Java which is really time taking process. Approx it is taking 4 to 5 hours.

Can I increase my performance by any change? Is there any technology or any tool or framework which I can integrate with java and increase my performance?

I have used following approaches.

1) Apache Drill- I am performing a join queries 
  Result : Drill is throwing Drillbit down exception as file size is too much.

2) Apache Beam- I am performing joining on files using parallel processing.
  Result : it is giving me Out Of Memory exception at group by feature.

I am reading this data from hadoop.

Comment: Why do you need to download the data for local processing with Java? Could you process the data directly with a tool like Hive instead?

Comment: Have you increased your beam executors or drill bit heap sizes? Hive, Spark, or Pig are all fine tools typical in most hadoop distributions

Comment: Please include your Beam code and clarify which version of the Beam SDK and which runner you're using.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i increase drill bit heap to 7GB and tried but still no luck. :( and i made the beam executor count to 2000 which is max but still it wont work.

Comment: First thing :: can i process these much amount of data by Beam or Drill or not.. Will these tools are supported. ?

Comment: Where did you install the services? Running Drill or Beam on a single computer with only 8 GB RAM obviously can't process the data. Drill is typically installed alongside the datanodes in the hadoop cluster, and in theory can process TB worth of files. I've not actually used Beam, but I think it just executes Spark or Flink jobs in YARN. Please edit your question to clarify what Java code you have. Is it MapReduce, Spark, or something else?

Comment: Beam jobs running on the Dataflow runner have been known to successfully process multiple petabytes of data in a single job. That said, it's definitely possible to write a program that will have an Out Of Memory due to suboptimal use of the Beam APIs. To get more detailed advice, you'll need to include some code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Hadoop and Spark because Spark uses in-memory model which is faster than Map Reduce.
Maybe these two links will help you:

https://content.pivotal.io/blog/3-key-capabilities-necessary-for-text-analytics-natural-language-processing-in-the-era-of-big-data

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/84781/spark-text-analytics-uncovering-data-driven-topics.html

Comment: Drill also uses a memory model for processing hadoop data

Comment: @cricket_007 OP has added some additional information (including Drill and Beam information) after my answer. So I couldn't know what tools he uses. So why downvoting me???

Comment: My bad. "I suggest Spark" + [some links is not entirely an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). It also didn't suggest MapReduce was being used. That "Java process" could already be Spark.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok. I understand your point. But I think, that I didn't deserve down vote. I just didn't want to copy information from some links. Orginal post was completely different. Anyway it is up to you.

Comment: If you update your answer to include some Spark code that joins two dataframes based on the conditions given in the question, I'll revert.